# Can't import/load data to hive, why?

Tags: hadoop, permissions, hive, load

I'm trying to import data (simple file with two columns, int and string), table looks:

```
hive> describe test;
id      int
name    string
```

and when I try to import:

```
hive> load data inpath '/user/test.txt' overwrite into table test;
Loading data to table default.test
rmr: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=hadoop, access=ALL, inode="/user/hive/warehouse/test":hive:hadoop:drwxrwxr-x
Failed with exception org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=hadoop, access=WRITE, inode="/user/hive/warehouse/test":hive:hadoop:drwxrwxr-x
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask
```

Looks like user hadoop has all permissions, but still can't load data, however I was able to create table.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Hive uses Metastore for it's metadata. All table definitions are created in it, but actual data stored in *hdfs*. Currently hive permissions and *hdfs* permissions are completely different things. They are unrelated. You have several workarounds:

1. Disable permissions at all (for hdfs hdfs)
2. Use Storage Based https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+Authorization (in this case you will not be able to create tables, if you don't own database directory on hdfs)
3. Submit all jobs under hive user ( sudo -u hive hive )
4. Create database:

   `create database hadoop;`

and create needed directory in *hdfs* with correct permissions

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/hive/warehouse/hadoop.db; 
hdfs dfs -chown hadoop:hive /user/hive/warehouse/hadoop.db
hdfs dfs -chmod g+w /user/hive/warehouse/hadoop.db
```

Of course, you should enable `hive.metastore.client.setugi=true` and `hive.metastore.server.setugi=true`. These parameters instruct hive execute jobs under current shell user (looks like these parameters are already enabled, because hive can't create directory).

Answer (score 2):

This issue is because of syntax.

The format given for generating a table should be similar to the input file format.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a permission error on the destination directory in the HDFS. An approach that worked for me:

1. identify the destination dir in the HDFS, hive > describe extended [problem table name]; under location parameter, if you don't know where that is, then
2. change the permissions on that directory:

> hadoop fs -chmod [-R] nnn /problem/table/directory

May have to run as superuser depending on your setup. Use the -R option to apply new permissions to everything within the directory. Choose nnn to whatever is appropriate for your system.